# Mac OS Catalina zshell : cat -A is illegal so what's is the substitute?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, zsh

In a typical linux system we can use `cat -A [file]` to output the file with tabs shown as `^I` and a `$` sign at the true end of the line which indicates how many spaces are there at the end of the line.

But in my Mac OS Calatlina zsh terminal, I get the following error

```
tilak@Tilaks-Macbook-Pro ~ % cat -A file.txt
cat: illegal option -- A
usage: cat [-benstuv] [file ...]
tilak@Tilaks-Macbook-Pro ~ %
```

I have tried `cat -tv [file]` but that has the same output as `cat [file]`

Here is the cat manual for -tv options...

> -t      Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and  display
>                tab characters as `^I'.
>
> -v      Display non-printing characters so they are visible.  Control
>                characters print as `^X' for control-X; the delete character
>                (octal 0177) prints as `^?'.  Non-ASCII characters (with the high
>                bit set) are printed as `M-' (for meta) followed by the character
>                for the low 7 bits.

idk if it helps but ...
Currently referring book: William Shotts - A Linux Command Line complete introduction _ (No Starch Press 2019)

Comment: `cat -tv` works for me. Are you sure your file *has* any non-printing characters?

Comment: Also, you can install GNU `cat` if you like. This isn't really a Linux-vs-macOS question, beyond which version of `cat` is installed by default in each OS.

Comment: To add to that, `cat` is independent of which shell you're using.

Comment: @chepner echo "sample                " > s.txt ; cat -tv s.txt do you see a dollar at the end of spaces ?  . That's what I am trying to ask

Comment: You need the `-e` option as well.

Comment: Not exactly the same but I use `sed -n l` for this purpose. It has the advantage of being more portable.

Comment: @TilakMaddy: I would install the gnu tools via _homebrew_, as described [here](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/). Note that you can optionally install them with a `g` prepended to their names, to avoid breaking existing shell scripts. If you follow this advice, your `cat` will become `gcat` and gladly accept your `-A` switch.

Comment: If your question would be closed here, I suggest to check also https://unix.stackexchange.com or on https://apple.stackexchange.com , where it would be likely on-topic.